# ubuntu 11.10 64 bit vs 32 bit

Tags: mongodb, ubuntu, 32bit-64bit

I recently got an upgrade at my work from macbook pro to a kickass desktop.
It has over 16 gigs of ram and a TB harddisk.
I am mostly an ubuntu fan.
In macbook pro I had a 32 bit version of ubuntu 11.10 and everything was pretty smooth.
But I did hit one bottle neck when I tried to use mongodb.It turns out there is a 2gb space limitation on a 32 bit version of mongodb.
Besides that I never didnt had any issues.
So most of my code (in python ) is wrriten on 32 bit machine.
Will it break anything if I install a 64 bit version.
I want to make full use of this horse power hence I am pretty inclined to install 64 bit but what does the great experience oracle of stackoverflow has to suggest.. :)
THanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, please use 64-bit. Avoid using 32-bit MongoDB if at all possible. Nothing should break with 64-bit, it should all work better.

That stated, do keep an eye out for any differences between 32-bit and 64-bit **python**. Upgrading should not cause a problem, but you will want to run your unit tests and ensure everything is kosher.